# How to make my question clearer?

Tags: support, specific-question

I have reworded my original question, [How do we create a better definition (for my definition of average) which is easier to compute and gives exact values?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3606899/how-do-we-create-a-better-definition-for-my-average-which-is-easier-to-compute-a)

Is it clear now? If not, what parts are unclear and how do I improve it?

Comment: One piece of advice of advice: Think more carefully before you edit the question (69 is clearly too much) as every time you are bumping your post.

Comment: @YuiToCheng I really want to make it clear. I could wait years till I gain enough knowledge but that will take forever. I see too much and know too little.

Comment: The problem is that the question will bump to the top every time you edit. @Arbuja That will be quite annoying for others.